# How does one enter the varying statement in a loop of a function requiring two input statements?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, apply, roc

I am new in R and have searched, but not found a query/answer that could satisfy my needs for what I am trying to write a script for. I am trying to loop the roc() function in the pROC package to calculate several parameters for multiple ROC curves. My Data looks like this, only with a lot more rows and columns (my df is called ROCTest5 in the code further down):

`Outcome      A     B     C     D     E BiOutcome
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
  Good    21151. 4966. 1943. 646.  277.         1.
  Good    46278. 9408. 2810. 906.  856.         1.
  Poor     4717. 2153.  758. 215.  148.         0.
  Poor    14488. 4661. 1167. 530.  299.         0.`

If I run each ROC analysis manually, which is not an option for larger data sets, I would use the following code:

```
ROCvirus = roc(ROCTest5$Outcome,
            ROCTest5$A,
            plot=TRUE, grid=TRUE,
            print.auc=TRUE, show.thres=TRUE)

aucA = auc(ROCvirus, as.vector=T)

ROCViCoorBest = coords(ROCvirus,"best",input=c("threshold", "specificity", "sensitivity", "accuracy",
                                       "tn", "tp", "fn", "fp", "npv", "ppv"), as.list=T)
```

The code I have been trying to use for creating a loop, looks like this:

```
library(pROC)

rocData = NULL
for(i in ROCTest5[A:E]){
 rocValue = roc(ROCTest5$Outcome,
             ROCTest5[[i in A:E]], #issue is here!
             plot=FALSE, auc=TRUE)
rocCoordi = coords(rocValue,"best",input=c("threshold", "specificity", "sensitivity", "accuracy",
                                         "tn", "tp", "fn", "fp", "npv", "ppv"))
rocValue = rbind(rocValue,rocCoordi)
rocData = cbind(rocData,rocValue)
}
```

This code doesn't work, as I am not correctly entering the statements for the second input parameter, which is the one to be changed with each iteration of the loop. I have tried several different ways of doing this e.g. with a second "for" statement, but fail to make the script work. I have also attempted scripting this with the "apply" functions, but run into the same general issue.
How does one enter the varying statement in a loop of a function requiring two input statements?
If you have a correction for the code, or for that matter an entirely different approach to achieving my goal, I am all ears. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to use different `in`s. On your line `ROCTest5[[i in A:E]]` you should change it to `ROCTest5[[i %in% A:E]]`, which is actually calling the `match` function underneath.

Comment: Thank you C.Braun, that makes sense. However, I must have another bug in my code, as I get an error even after adding %in%: `Error in check_names_df(i, x) : object 'A' not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to approach this problem is to use an apply statement.  In base R, you can do this by calling

```
list_of_results <- lapply(LETTERS[1:5], function(x) {
  ROCvirus = roc(ROCTest5$Outcome,
        ROCTest5[[x]],
        plot=TRUE, grid=TRUE,
        print.auc=TRUE, show.thres=TRUE)
  auc_result <- auc(ROCvirus, as.vector=T)
  ROCViCoorBest = coords(ROCvirus,"best",ret=c("threshold", "specificity", "sensitivity", "accuracy",
                                       "tn", "tp", "fn", "fp", "npv", "ppv"), as.list=T)
  list(ROCvirus = ROCvirus, auc = auc_result, ROCViCoorBest = ROCViCoorBest)
})
```

which should return a list of length 5, with the results of A in first entry, ... to results of E in the 5th entry.

The contents of the function are taken directly from the first block of code you added.  To work with the list, you can extract elements.  Looking at the help file for `coords`, it looks like that returns a vector, so we can do:

```
rocValue <- sapply(list_of_results, function(x) { x$ROCViCoorBest})
```

This will be a matrix, probably the transpose of what you want.  Use `t` to transpose it.

Comment: Thank you Melissa, that works like a charm!

For others that might read this, the line in my code that says input=c should read ret=c

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you!    Could you please accept the answer in that case?  Thanks!  (I've also editted my answer to change `input=c(` to `ret=c(`.  Is that the change you meant?

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant :)
The combined data list was somewhat unstructured, so I fiddled with it a bit to produce a more ordered output. I'll post that below. It could probably be done more eloquently by others, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The script below works, and produces an ordered df:

```
list_of_results = lapply(LETTERS[1:5], function(x) {
ROCvirus = roc(ROCTest5$Outcome,
             ROCTest5[[x]])
auc_result = auc(ROCvirus)
ROCViCoorBest = coords(ROCvirus,"best",
                     ret=c("threshold", "specificity",
                           "sensitivity", "accuracy"),
                     best.method="closest.topleft")
ROCDat = c(as.numeric(auc_result), as.numeric(ROCViCoorBest))

list(ROCDat = ROCDat)
})  
Lab = c("AUC","threshold", "specificity",
      "sensitivity", "accuracy")
OutputData=as.data.frame(list_of_results)
OutputData=cbind(Lab,OutputData)

OutputData
```

`Lab             ROCDat     ROCDat.1     ROCDat.2     ROCDat.3    ROCDat.4
AUC         7.592593e-01    0.8518519    0.9074074    0.9074074   0.7962963
threshold   1.475129e+04 5395.7471701 2361.0867577 1072.7211367 361.2662753
specificity 6.666667e-01    0.7777778    0.7777778    0.7777778   0.7777778
sensitivity 6.666667e-01    0.8333333    0.8333333    1.0000000   0.8333333
accuracy    6.666667e-01    0.8000000    0.8000000    0.8666667   0.8000000`